# Scoverage: Ambiguous measurement from branch coverage

Tags: scala, code-coverage, scoverage

I have noticed that all the tests with no control-flow (such as if, else, switch, etc) shows 100% branch coverage due to no branch present in the code block. For example

```
def foo = {
println("Hello World!") 
}
```

Shows 100% branch coverage and 0 % statement coverage. This is due to 0/0 branch covered. From my eyes, I see one branch in above test case, so shouldn't there be one branch even if there is no control flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess its semantics. The code can only follow one path - so it can never "branch". Or do you consider the whole thing to be one branch.

If you have a train track which is a straight line, how many branches does it have ?

Does this have 2 branches, or 3 ?

```
def foo = {
  if (b) 
   println("1")
  else
   println("2)
}
```

At the very least I think we could update scoverage so that your example is 100% branch coverage, but should it say 0 branches or 1...

Comment: I see two branches in above example. You have a good point. However seen 100% coverage on a class just because it had not branch was confusing. Especially when there was no test for the class.

Comment: I suppose the rules should be, if you have 1 (or 0 branches), but no coverage then you have 0% branch coverage. If you have 1 or 0 branches and at least one statement covered, then you have 100% branch coverage.

Comment: One question, are you going to update the Scoverage witih suggested changes?

Comment: Next week turned into next month but its been committed now.